# Possible to populate a Google Form's Questions with a Spreadsheet / CSV?

Tags: forms, csv, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

I have scoured the internet, and although I am fairly sure this just isn't possible *yet* due to the design of forms by google, but if anyone has a way to do it, be it through running a script or just a clever work around, it would help me so much!

Allow me to break down kind of what I am trying to get done:

I have a spread sheet, with about 600+ entries in it.

I need to take, and populate a form with each question being a row form the spreadsheet, and each question having a blank short-text answer.

I am trying to populate the questions with English phrases, so a third party can easily fill in the spanish translation in the `Answer` spaces.

I can only find way to populate the `Answer` with spreadsheet data (by copy pasting a column into multiple choice answer, for example), but I need it to populate the `Question`, leaving blank answers.

TL:DR I want to be able to make a 600 question form, with each question being populated from a row in my .csv/spreadsheet.

Is this possible? I do feel like I could've worded this question better, if anyone is confused as to what I'm asking please let me know and i will revise!

Thanks